# Changing listview background colour based on value xamarin xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin

So i have a list view that is bound to ProductLines.  Basically its a list of products, when you load, it will auto load any cached items from sqlite db. you can add to it and then when you save it will store it into a database located on another server.  Below i have been experimenting with functions and colours etc.  But what I really would like to do is on initial load show the background colour of red or white in the list of products.  This is based on if it has failed to save to another servers database. 
Also when i go to save everything from the list, it basically loops over the datasource and attempts to call a stored proc.  If it fails it will set the bit of that line to true as if it failed.  When it reloads the list it will display red/white based on the bit...Or if there is another way to update background colour cell based on the value of what it is bound too in that item that would be great.

```
        <ListView x:Name="ProductLines"  Grid.Row="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell Tapped="Cell_OnAppearing">
                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" 
                    Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding ProductLineDisplayName}"
                            TextColor="#f35e20" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
                <!--<TextCell Text="{Binding ProductLineDisplayName}" TextColor="DarkGray"/>-->
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the problem. TextColor is a Bindable Property. You can bind it to a property of type `Color`, or to a different type property and use a `IValueConverter` to convert from property of type X to `Color`.

Remember also this:

Application developers can specify colors in XAML either as a hexadecimal number or as a valid color name.

When specifying a color with a hexadecimal number, app developers can use 3, 4, or 6 digits. If the developer specifies 3 digits, they are interpreted as RGB doublet data for a fully opaque color. For example, "#123" specifies the color that is represented by "#FF112233". If the developer provides a 4-digit hexadecimal number, then the data are interpreted as above, except that the first digit specifies the alpha channel. For example, "#1234" specifies the color that is represented by "#11223344". Finally, if the developer provides a 6 digit hexadecimal number, the data are interpreted as a fully opaque color with those RGB values. For example, "#112233" specifies the color that is represented by "#FF112233".

When specifying a color with a string, app developers can use color name in isolation, or prefix it with "Color.". For example, both Purple and Color.Purple are valid ways to specify the color purple. The following table describes the valid color names that can be used to specify colors in XAML.